# AS3 Using currentLabel to reference an already named MC

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Novice Flash dev here.  I'm having a bit of trouble passing the name of an existing MC on my stage to a new variable and then tweening it.  I've tried everything I could find.
Here is the set-up:

3 levels of question difficulty: Easy, Moderate, Hard.  Each question is a seperate MC in the library.
Each question has two strings of text: one normal and one altered.
container_MC contains all of the questions.
Inside container_MC each frame contains one of the question MCs along with a second MC called highlight.
Each of these frames is then labeled with the difficulty of the question and the question number i.e. easyQuestion1.
Highlight is a MC containing a box that surrounds the alteration.  It is labled the same as the frame +"Highlight" i.e. easyQuestion1Highlight.
Each of the highlight boxes has Alpha =0.
Each frame also contains the variables that determine the correct answer and the difficulty of the question.
NONE of the objects on the stage have been added dynamically with addChild (note the Novice portion of my intro :D).

On my maintimeline I have one instance of container_MC.  If the player selects the correct answer the current frames highlight box changes from Alpha =0 to Alpha =1.
What I am trying to do is pass the frameLabel as part of the name of the MC.  Here is some code to examine.

```
import com.greensock.*

container_MC.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,continueQuestions);

function continueQuestions(evt:Event){
    evt.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,continueQuestions);
}

var myVar:String=(container_MC.currentLabel);//Trace returns easyQuestion1.
var myVar2:String=(myVar+"Highlight");//Trace returns easyQuestion1Highlight.
var highlightVar:MovieClip= MovieClip(container_MC.myVar2);//Trace returns null.

nextQuestion_btn.addEventListener(evt:MouseEvent.CLICK, nextQuestion);

function rightAnswer(e:Event):void{
    tweenMax.to(highlightVar, 1, {autoAlpha:1});
}

function nextQuestion(e:Event):void{
    tweenMax.to(highlightVar, .25, {autoAlpha:0});
    container_MC.nextFrame();
}
```

In the actual code, nextQuestion has a group of if//else if conditionals controlling where the player goes.  However for our purposes it just needs to work with the next frame's highlight box.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question! What you need to do is change this line:

```
var highlightVar:MovieClip= MovieClip(container_MC.myVar2);
```

...to this instead:

```
var highlightVar:MovieClip= MovieClip(container_MC.getChildByName(myVar2));
```

This is because expressing "container_MC.myVar2" means "on container, look for property named myVar2", hence "myVar2" get's used as a literal String and not as a variable reference. Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect!  That was exactly what I needed.  You sir are a scholar and a gentleman!